# Jenkins Multibranch pipeline lftp cannot upload because of Certificate error

Tags: angular, jenkins, lftp

I'm trying to deploy my **Angular** app automatically with **Jenkins** using **LFTP**.

To do this I created the following **jenkinsfile** :

```
node {
 stage("Clearing Workspace"){
  deleteDir()
 }
stage("Checkout"){
checkout scm
}
stage('npm install') {
sh 'npm install'
 }
 stage('Build angular app') {
sh 'ng build --prod'
}
stage('Push to server') {
sh' lftp -e "mirror -R ./dist /test" -u eatsma,PASSWORD myDomain.de'
}

}
```

Unfortunately i'm getting this error at the last stage:

> mirror: Fatal error: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name 'myDomain.de' (60:0A:B2:25:99:3F:24:71:0D:C9:4F:D2:64:CE:D5:82:54:1D:DF:B3)

would be great if someone could help me